# ember "Uncaught Error: Could not find module handlebars"

Tags: ember.js

```
Uncaught Error: Could not find module handlebarsember.prod.js:35
```

I am using requirejs with ember 1.9.1 and handlebars.runtime 2.0.0.

My Shim:

```
shim : {
    ember: {
        deps: [
            'jquery',
            'handlebars'
        ],
        exports: 'Ember'
    },
    handlebars: {
        exports: 'Handlebars'
    }....
```

I keep getting this error:

Uncaught Error: Could not find module handlebars

Is 1.9.1 compatible with handlebars 2.0.0? When I rollback to 1.3.x the error goes away.

Any ideas what is up with 2.0.0 and what the fix is?

Comment: Similar issue logged here - https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/9879

Answer (score 1):

Handlebars 2.0.0 doesn't expose the global `window.Handlebars` variable that Ember expects to be there. I'm doing something like this to compensate:

```
define(['handlebars'], function (Handlebars) {
  window.Handlebars = Handlebars;

  require(['ember'], function () {
    // ...
  });
});
```

Comment: Where do you put this code? I tried adding it to my main.js, but I'm getting an error "Mismatched anonymous define() module: function (Handlebars)"

Comment: I put it directly into my manifest for RequireJS, after the `requirejs.config()` stuff. If you have a `main.js` where you set up your app and stuff, you might want to change my code about to add a `require(['main'])` where the `...` is. Also, this might help with your error: http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html